# Oracle SQL Developer - using foreign keys

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, foreign-key-relationship

First of, this is a pretty basic question but I cant seem to find a basic tutorial on how to use the software.

If i have a table named `COUNTRY` with the field `region_id`
and then another table named `REGION` with a primary key as `region_id`.

I want to set the region_id field in `COUNTRY` table as a foreign key.
Are the following steps correct?

- Go to constraints, add a new foreign key.
- Select `COUNTRY` as table
- Change local column to `region_id`

![enter image description here][1]
Am I doing it correctly? if not, where am i going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, This is the correct procedure.

If you want your foreign key to have additional behavior (e.g., `ON DELETE CASCADE`), you can use the "on delete" drop-down in the wizard.

Comment: What would on delete cascade allow it to do?

Comment: @ili `on delete cascade` means that when you delete a `region` with `country`s pointing to it, they will also be deleted. This is not necessarily the correct behavior for your usecsae, but if it is, this would allow the database to do it for you instead of you having to code it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant seem to find a basic tutorial on how to use the software.

Have you looked at the [Oracle Learning Library](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:1:0) for SQL Developer tutorials?

If you search for: Getting Started with Oracle SQL Developer 4.0 you will find a tutorial that gets you up and running SQL Developer, this tutorial includes how to create Foreign Key Constraints.